# Query to solve a rolling issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am seeking guidance on how to solve the following issue?
My data look like:

| id | Total | Allowed | Left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 815 | 150 | 655 |
| 2 | 815 | 15 | 650 |
| 3 | 815 | 135 | 515 |
| 4 | 815 | 1380 | -864 |
| 5 | 815 | 109 | -974 |
| 6 | 815 | 10 | -984 |

"Left" column is derived from difference of Total and Allowed and then it rolls to next row with Left - Allowed to set value of Left in next rows.

I want to create a new column of Final where if Left value is greater than Allowed, then set the value of Final as Allowed; however, where Left value is less than Allowed, set the value Final for all such rows to 0 except for first row where Left value was less than 0 and set it to the value of last positive Left value. Output should be like this:

| id | Total | Allowed | Left | Final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 815 | 150 | 655 | 150 |
| 2 | 815 | 15 | 650 | 15 |
| 3 | 815 | 135 | 515 | 135 |
| 4 | 815 | 1380 | -864 | 515 |
| 5 | 815 | 109 | -974 | 0 |
| 6 | 815 | 10 | -984 | 0 |

The way I tried to do is:

```
Update table
set Final = 
Case when Left >=  Allowed then Left End
```

However, i do not understand how to do the remaining part. I am new to this site and let me know if more details are required to help provide solution to me.

Comment: Please remove any reference to urgent as per the [site guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: We do not provide URGENT help here. No question is more important than any other, and you're asking for free help from people who volunteer their time to help others. If you can't be patient and need immediate help, hire someone and pay them a rate sufficiently high to get their immediate attention. Otherwise, you can wait your turn like everyone else and hope one of those volunteers offers to help. We are also not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Apologies as i am new to this site and did not know the rules for posting a question. Appreciate if you can please guide. Thanks a lot

Comment: You need a column that indicates what is the "next row". Otherwise this can't be done.

Comment: Can you please provide the logic for this? I can create new column if required. but please if you can post the code for how to do this.

Comment: "last positive Left value" There is no definition of the "last" record here. Even though you have posted records in a certain order, you actually need a column that indicates this order, for example an additional column that has an intenger or a datetime that tells you what order the records are in.

Comment: id column refers to this and assume this is in ascending order and these are all rows i have.

Comment: Can you add some more sample rows from row 7 onward, where Left > Allowed. Does this FInal go back to Allowed?, or does it stay 0?

Comment: These are the only 6 rows sorted on id basis. We need to define query on basis of only these 6 rows. There are no additional rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use an updatable CTE

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT *,
      f = CASE WHEN [Left] > Allowed THEN Allowed
               WHEN [Left] > 0 THEN [Left]
               WHEN LAG([Left]) OVER (ORDER BY id) > 0 THEN LAG([Left]) OVER (ORDER BY id)
               ELSE 0 END
    FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE t
SET Final = f;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=383074af0d9a63574d78d5ddedc42975)